# Sass-lint vs Style-lint?

Tags: stylelint, sass-lint

Which one would you recommend, [Sass-lint](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint) or [Style-lint](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint)? Why? (They seem to be very similar to me)

Comment: I'm using sass-lint now, however, am considering switching to stylelint as it seems it can calculate specificity and apply rules based on that.